# Can I use boost::format with zero-based argument indexes?

Tags: c++, boost, string-formatting

We have a large code base using string interpolation like `_("%0% has a %1%.  The %1% belongs to %0%").arg('Bob').arg('dog')`, using zero-based indices.

We would like to harness the power of [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/format/doc/format.html), which uses one-based placeholders.

Knowing that the Boost guys design their libraries with extension in mind, is there a way to tell `boost::format` that our placeholders are zero-based and not one-based?

Comment: I don't want to be pessimistic but looking at [their code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/format/format_class.hpp) it seems that the one-based indices are hard-coded... So you would have to modify every places where it is assumed. However the implementation uses zero-based indices, so you may just have to modify the interface.

Comment: what's the use case? i.e. What is generating the current strings?

Comment: If you have a good code editor that does file search and replace and the highest index you use is not astronomical, start with the highest known index in your codebase and just do (assuming your highest index is %10%), "replace "%10% with %11%", then "replace "%9% with %10%", etc. until you get to "replace "%0% with %1%".